# How to use System.Data.SQLite.Linq

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite

I was wondering how to just use System.Data.SQLite.Linq to query SQLite database, without Entity Framework involved.

I had used decompiler tool to check System.Data.SQLite.Linq and System.Data.SQLite.EF6, it seems like they are the same except the namespace and EntityFramework is referenced by the latter.

I see the following description on the official website:
http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki
[image]

As far as I understand, any package that support Linq should implement the IQueryProvider and IQueryable interfaces, but I don't see this in package System.Data.SQLite.Linq.

Can someone explain it? Thanks a lot！

Answer (score 2):

I have analysed their sources and cannot even understand for which purpose it was introduced and how it is related with LINQ.

If you need good SQLite LINQ support without EF, I know only one library which can do that effectively [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) (disclaimer, I'm one of the creators)